# Making a form letter with PHP with text content from a variable from the POST

Tags: php, forms, parsing

I am trying to make a form letter using PHP. I have a view that has a text area that has some pre-populated text. The text is like a letter: Dear So-and-so, etc.

There are a few places that I need to fill in specific, dynamic data from the db, but otherwise I need to let the user change the wording of the other parts of the email as necessary. I am thinking of putting a random character sequence to mark each place I am going to insert a new value.

So I submit the form to a PHP page and I pull the text out into a string variable. As I get ready to email it off I need to make sure that those placeholders are updated. How can I replace the contents of the string variable with the value of a variable?

EDIT - Example. This is what I currently have inside of the string variable in the PHP file that is processing the action of the form.

Hi %@

I hope you are doing well. I wanted to remind you that in %@ days you need to do something.

As a team we are currently at %@ percent.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use to do is something like as follows.

```
$email_text = "Hello ###user###,    
                  You have a new Event on ###date### at ###time### for ###hours### hour.    
                  Please let me know if you are attending. 

                  Have Fun.
                  ###site###";

$email_text =   str_replace('###user###',$username,$email_text);
$email_text =   str_replace('###date###',date('M dS, Y', strtotime($date)),$email_text);
$email_text =   str_replace('###time###',$time,$email_text);
$email_text =   str_replace('###hours###',$hours,$email_text);
$email_text =   str_replace('###site###',$site,$email_text);
```

I hope this will make pretty much clear that, how you can work this out.

Comment: All of these answers look like they'd work, but I feel this one is most relevant to my current situation. Thank you for sharing such a clear example!

Comment: @oof gwen Don't you think using strstr is more efficient and clear than using str_replace function for each placeholde

Comment: there are multiple ways for every piece of code to work for you. This is just a small part of code, but actually when template / variable changes dynamically or conditionally, this is the best way to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming letter text being like this:

> Dear %name%! I'm from %city%. Let's go to %destination%.

Your code should be like this:

```
$letter_text = $_POST["letter_text"];
foreach(array("name", "city", "destination") as $var) {
  $letter_text = str_replace("%".$var."%", $_POST[$var], $letter_text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following several times. Hope this solves what you are looking for.

```
<?php

$content = "Hi #user, 
Thanks for registering. Your username is #username.
"

$trans = array("#user" => "ABC", "#username"=> "XYZ");

echo strtr($content, $trans);

?>
```

I think this is you can use easily. Just change content variable to whatever your string is and placeholders( starting with #) to your placeholders. set the values in $trans array for these placeholders from database or from $_POST whatever your need is.

Comment: @oof gwen Don't you think using strstr is more efficient and clear than using str_replace function for each placeholder.

Comment: I don't really know what strstr() does so the other option seemed easier. Thanks for your answer though!